# using variable in PowerShell array element

Tags: arrays, powershell

How to I add variables data inside the string element of an array? If I do `$s.Length`, the output is 1 instead of 2.

```
$IPAddress = '192.168.1.1'
[string[]]$s = (
    'https://google.com/' + $IPAddress + '/hostname',
    'https://google.com/' + $IPAddress + '/DNS'
)
foreach ($element in $s) {
    Write-Host $element
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish what you are trying (string expansion) is:

```
$s = "https://google.com/$IPAddress/hostname",
        "https://google.com/$IPAddress/DNS"
```

By using double quotes it will automatically expand `$IPAddress` within the strings. This works best when the variable is a string, as more complex objects may not perform as expected. If you need to reference a property of an object in this manner you will need to wrap it in `$()`, for example `"Hello $($User.Name)!"` to expand the `Name` property of the `$User` object.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`$s` contains a single string because of the way you define the array. The concatenation operator (`+`) has a weaker [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-3.0) than the array construction operator (`,`). Because of that a statement

```
'foo' + $v + 'bar', 'foo' + $v + 'baz'
```

actually works like this:

```
'foo' + $v + @('bar', 'foo') + $v + 'baz'
```

Due to the string concatenation operation the array is mangled into a space-separated string (the separator is defined in the [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-3.0) `$OFS`), resulting in this:

```
'foo' + $v + 'bar foo' + $v + 'baz'
```

To avoid this behavior you need to either put the concatenation operations in grouping expressions:

```
$s = ('https://google.com/' + $IPAddress + '/hostname'),
     ('https://google.com/' + $IPAddress + '/DNS')
```

or inline the variables (requires double-quoted strings):

```
$s = "https://google.com/${IPAddress}/hostname",
     "https://google.com/${IPAddress}/DNS"
```

You could also use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx), but that requires grouping expressions as well:

```
$s = ('https://google.com/{0}/hostname' -f $IPAddress),
     ('https://google.com/{0}/DNS' -f $IPAddress)
```

---

**Side note:** Casting the variable to `[string[]]` is optional. Using the comma operator will give you an array even without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

TheMadTechnician beat me to it by a few seconds, but if you prefer to construct the string expressions explicitly, wrap them in parens:

```
$IPAddress = '192.168.1.1'
[string[]]$s = (
        ('https://google.com/'+$IPAddress+'/hostname'),
        ('https://google.com/'+$IPAddress+'/DNS'))
foreach ($element in $s) 
{
Write-Host $element
}
```

The parens force the expressions inside to be evaluated first.